# How to express Dirac delta-function in functional form?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, path-integral, dirac-delta-distributions

In the paper written by Dmitry Bagrets, Alexander Altland and AlexKamenev (Sachdev–Ye–Kitaev model as Liouville quantum mechanics: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0550321316302206?via%3Dihub , http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.nuclphysb.2016.08.002 , ***open access***, [arXiv:1607.00694](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.00694)), they introduced an identity, equation (5):
$$1=\int {D}G\delta(NG_{\tau,\tau^{\prime}}+A_{\tau,\tau^{\prime}})=\int DGD\Sigma e^{\frac{1}{2}\int d\tau\int d\tau^{\prime}\Sigma_{\tau,\tau^{\prime}}(NG_{\tau,\tau^{\prime}}+A_{\tau,\tau^{\prime}})} .\tag{5}$$
They said, we need $G_{\tau,\tau^{\prime}}=-\frac{1}{N}A_{\tau,\tau^{\prime}}$, and $\Sigma_{\tau,\tau^{\prime}}$ is the ***Lagrange multiplier*** (real field). Does this mean
$$\int D\Sigma e^{\Sigma(NG+A)}=\delta(NG+A)~?$$

I do not understand the upper equation, because in my mind we have
$$\int \frac{dx}{2\pi}e^{iax}=\delta(a).$$
And why is $\Sigma_{\tau,\tau^{\prime}}$ called ***Lagrange multiplier***?

Answer (score 4):

Indeed,
$$\int D\Sigma \,e^{i \int_{\tau,\tau'}\Sigma_{\tau,\tau'}G_{\tau,\tau'} }=\int D\Sigma \,e^{i S[\Sigma]}=\prod_{\tau,\tau'}\delta(G_{\tau,\tau'})$$
is just a generalization of 
$$\int dx\, e^{i a x}=\delta (a).$$
Note that sometimes the $i$ in the path integral is omitted. This is under the assumption that the analytical continuation $\Sigma\to -i\Sigma$ is allowed (this can be sometimes justified in perturbation theory, but it might also not be allowed non-perturbatively). This is usually done to render the minimum of the action (and thus the Lagrange multiplier, see below) real.

$\Sigma$ is sometimes called a Lagrange multiplier (somewhat abusively), because a mean-field (or equivalently a stationary phase) approximation of $\int D\Sigma \,e^{i S[\Sigma]}$ is given by the extremization of $S[\Sigma]$, that is, for $\delta S/\delta \Sigma=0$ (in addition to other mean-field terms coming from the integration over $G$ and other fields).

In this approximation, $\Sigma$ exactly plays the role of a Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: Thank you, but there is no $i$ in the equation (5) and this is what I do not really understand.

Comment: See my edit, which explains why the $i$ can be omitted.

Comment: @ShengLiu : stated otherwise, do the calculation in mean-field with and without the $i$, and you'll see that the end result will be the same.

Comment: I do not see why the first relation (in the answer) would hold by an analytical continuation of some sort. For example, it does not hold if one applies the same "analytical continuation" to $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx \, e^{i a x}$.
I see the relation in the aforementioned paper more in the direction of Hubbard-Stratonovich transformations.

Comment: @PhilosophiaeNaturalis : This is definitely not a HS transformation (which uses gaussian functional integrals). As I wrote in the answer, this analytic continuation has to be justified (which is usually not done). However, in a large $N$ limit (as use here in the paper), a saddle point analysis is enough. One realizes (before doing this analytic continuation) that the location of the saddle-point is imaginary (i.e. $i\Sigma$ is real), and thus they prefer to do the analytic continuation before the saddle-point approximation. But this is not always justifiable (and correct).

Comment: @Adam: Invoking the notion of saddle-point made me more confused; can we find a saddle-point approximation to an integral like $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx \, e^{i a x}$ ?
Could you expand your answer by giving an explicit example, and/or providing a reference?

Comment: @Adam@PhilosophiaeNaturalis: After this question was posted, I asked a physicist who wrote a paper on SYK model, he replied, and I quote: "It is just a matter of convention here. At this early stage it is still possible to relabel a self-energy $\Sigma -> i\Sigma$ to get $i$ for the delta-function if you wish, because $\Sigma$ is an integration variable. At later stage $\Sigma$ is found from the saddle point analysis, and it will be shifted to the complex plane and become a pure imaginary (in this new convention)."

Comment: @ShengLiu : I of course agree, since it's I've written in my answer since the beginning ;) (although it is not only a matter of convention, there is the assumption that you can do this change of variable, which is the case here).

Comment: @PhilosophiaeNaturalis : No, you can't on this simple integral. But in the context of the SYK model, there are multiple functional integrals, and importantly, there is a large parameter ($N$), which justifies this saddle-point approximation. Have a look for instance here http://www.lptmc.jussieu.fr/files/chap_rg.pdf , starting at equation 7.523.

Comment: @Adam: Thanks for the ref.; but the relation itself (eq. 7.523) is _not_ related to a saddle-point approximation, as far as I see. Note for the saddle-point method, the function in the exponent should be convex.
Could you explain a bit more about the 2nd part of your answer, i.e., the analytical continuation, and the extremisation of $S[\Sigma]$?
I think your answer needs an extension to become clear.

Comment: @PhilosophiaeNaturalis : I wrote "starting at eq 7.523". The full path integral is eq. 7.524, and the saddle-point approx is done at 7.528. Here, $i\lambda$ is the same thing as $\Sigma$. Do the approximation, and you find that $\lambda$ is imaginary at the saddle-point. Or do the analytic continuation first, and you'll get the same end result.

Comment: @Adam: Our exchanges in comments clearly suggest that it will be worthwhile if you extend and clarify your answer by adding all these details you have referred to.

Comment: @ShengLiu: In my view, a sound (if not rigorous) mathematical basis for the relation is missing. The quotation from the physicist does not make the situation better.