# Functional integrations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, functional-determinants

We often see functional versions of Gaussian integrations $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d^dx e^{-x^{T}Mx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi^d \det M}} \to \int[\mathcal{D}X] e^{-i\int X \mathcal{O}X} = (\det{O})^{-1}$$
where $\mathcal{O}$ is some hermitian operator. The map to convert a gaussian integral into a path integral is very obvious here $$x \to X\\M \to \mathcal{O} $$
Similarly, is there a way to convert the following integral

$$\int^{\infty}_{0} dt~ e^{-st} = \frac{1}{s}$$

into a functional integral (or path integral over fields)?

Comment: First off, how do you suggest generalizing this to finite-dimensional integrals? i.e., with $\mathrm d^dt$ instead of $\mathrm dt$? If you don't know how to generalize it to higher-dimensional integrals then your chances of generalizing it to infinite-dimensional integrals are rather slim.

Answer (score -1):

The second integral's functional equivalent, say

\begin{equation}
    \int \mathcal{D}X e^{-i \int \mathcal{O} X}
\end{equation}

is just a Lagrange multiplier on the operator $\mathcal{O}$ so you'll just get a delta function on whatever the operator $\mathcal{O}$.
If you'd like to make this into a more precise answer, I suggest having a look into some algebraic QFT.
Also this is a similar question to [this entry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/353118/how-to-express-dirac-delta-function-in-functional-form).

Comment: But that is not correct right because I want $\mathcal{O}^{-1}$ and not $\delta(\mathcal{O})$.